# Can't able to connect my controller with html properly in Angular js

Tags: angularjs

**Here is my code, Cant able to do the Ajax call, Getting errors here. Don,t know how to clear that, can someone help me please.**

```js
 var app = angular.module('app',['ui.router']);

app.controller('PostCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
 console.log('inside jobpost');
    $http.get("/api/job-posts").success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.items = data.data;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("No data found..");
  });
});

app.filter('searchFor', function(){
    return function(arr, searchString){
        if(!searchString){
            return arr;
        }
        var result = [];
        searchString = searchString.toLowerCase();
        angular.forEach(arr, function(item){
            if(item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1){
            result.push(item);
        }
        });
        return result;
    };
}]);
```

```html
   <!-- <body ng-app="app"> -->
        <div ng-controller="PostCtrl">
            <h3 class="headName">Ajax search using AngularJs</h3>
            <div class="bar">
                <input type="text" class="search" ng-model="searchString" placeholder="Enter your search terms" />
            </div>
            <ul class="data-ctrl">
                <li ng-repeat="i in items | searchFor:searchString">
                    <p>{{i.title}}
                </li>
            </ul>
```

I try to solve that in many ways but can't able to clear.

Comment: what is the error in the console ?

Comment: Can you please Run the Code Snippet denny,

Comment: In my browser it doesn't show any html output and in my console also there is no console messages(Which i was given in console.log),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this... 
you are missing `)` in line 33

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ui.router']);

app.controller('PostCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
    console.log('inside jobpost');
    $http.get("/api/job-posts").success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.items = data.data;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("No data found..");
  });
}]);

app.filter('searchFor', function(){
    return function(arr, searchString){
        if(!searchString){
            return arr;
        }
        var result = [];
        searchString = searchString.toLowerCase();
        angular.forEach(arr, function(item){
            if(item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1){
                result.push(item);
            }
        });
        return result;
    };
});
```

Comment: Yah i was run that code now..But it says :  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )   in lineNumber 10 , Anyway thanks Durgpal